# Setting a pointer to NULL in Arduino library - error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: programming, library, pointer

I am writing my own library for using with my Arduino. In my code, if I set a pointer I have declared to `NULL`, such as

```
int *ptr=NULL;
```

I get the error

```
error: ‘NULL’ was not declared in this scope
```

I need to initialize it to `NULL` as I am using pointers to implement a list.

If I use `NULL` directly in the program in the IDE, I do not get this error. This seems to be happening only when it is a part of the library code.

How do I correct this? Is there any alternative keyword to use? Or do I have to include some library?

Thank you.

Comment: Works fine for me. No need to include anything. It is, actually, part of `stddef.h`, but that gets included by default anyway, and is used by many other headers, like `stdio.h`.

Comment: @Majenko Thank you. I checked, it works when I use directly. I forgot to mention that this error appears when I use `NULL` in a definition of a header file which I have written. I hadn't realized that it works otherwise. Edited by question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am writing my own library for using with my Arduino.

You should really include Arduino.h, i.e.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
```

Not only will that define `NULL` for you, but you also get the other standard Arduino functions like `digitalRead`, pin number declarations, and various useful macros.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any reason to prefer it over including individual libraries?

Comment: Including Arduino.h gives you all the stuff you should need (including the standard libraries). If you ever need something like a port or pin address, or any of the Arduino functions (like analogRead) you are going to have to include Arduino.h anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure your header includes the [`stddef.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stddef.h.html) header, which holds all these standard definitions (hence its name):

```
#include <stddef.h>
```